# Interpretation of FFT FMCW Doppler radar results

Tags: signal-processing, fft, radar

After a lot of research and help from the users here, I managed to do some FFT and signal processing in my first time in my life :)

I have got the following figure, which shows one peak frequency, but the strange thing is the range is 0, however I was putting the radar into a wall... so I expect at least some distance.. How would I interpret the results ? Is it a problem of coding ? or how would I verify that the signal processing is correct?
[image]

```
x = complex(ResultI, ResultQ); 

D = 64;

 N=512; %FFT size
m1=reshape(x,length(x)/D,D); %generating matrix ---> each row showing range info for one period AND each column showing number of periods
[My,Ny]=size(m1');
win=hamming(Ny);
m2=(win*ones(1,My));applying window for sidelobe reduction (in time domain)
M2=(fft(m2,2*N)); %First FFT for range information
M3=fftshift(fft(M2',2*D)); %Second FFT for doppler information
[My,Ny]=size(M3);
```

If anyone interested here is the I/Q data from 4 channels

and the full matlab code that reads the I/Q and do FFT on them
http://www.mediafire.com/file/gcj13keakb8mkf7/MATLAB.zip

Comment: I don't understand why you think that a FFT of the *spectrum* will give velocity information in a FMCW radar. The first FFT(which you do on time domain data) gives you both velocity *and* distance, it's just hard to separate them. Doing a FFT on that nets you the ...periodicity of the distance to targets, i guess?

Comment: @jms I have read many papers that says doing a second FFT will yeild the velocity... so how would I seperate the first FFT to get the velocity from it ?

Comment: @jms look at that excerpt of the paper https://imgur.com/a/RUUm66v

Comment: https://cstools.asme.org/csconnect/FileUpload.cfm?View=yes&ID=39498

Comment: @jms
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/fmcw-radar-need-for-second-stage-fft-for-velocity-determination

Comment: What are your comments ?

Comment: So you're sending multiple chirps and calculating the range-velocity data for every chirp with a FFT, as usual. Then you figure out the radial velocity of the targets by measuring the rate of change of phase over time (frequency) for each bin. Instead of basic differentiation of phase angle between the currently received bin and the previously received bin, you just compute the derivative of phase for each bin with another FFT. That makes sense. Explain your intentions with more detail next time.

Comment: The question is, is my code above is correct or should be there more considerations. Hope you answer me

Comment: What are the units of range and velocity on that chart? Is it just the index of the bin? You seem to be taking 512 samples for each FFT, but what's the sample rate? What's the rate of change of frequency of the transmitted chirps? You aren't providing enough information for an answer, which is why nobody bothers. I suspect that either your chirp rate is so low that a range of a few meters registers as zero, or that the strength of the echo is too low compared to the zero-distance spike to be seen on a linear chart. Take the logarithm of the vertical axis data and you should see more details.

Comment: @jms  Fs  = 125khz, Rate of change is 5800MhZ/12.uS

Comment: @jms please ask for more information if you want, Fc carrier 24Ghz

Comment: @jms how would I take the log of the vertical axis, I'm new to matlab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78039/discussion-between-jms-and-ahmed-saleh).

Comment: What is the chirp bandwidth? The chirp details should have been in the first question. Start frequency, end frequency, chirp duration, and chirp repetition rate. Also distance to wall.

Comment: @jms can you come to the chat ?